# What slaughter laws exist in the US and Europe?

Tags: united-states, european-union, food

I mean actual laws for industrial farms applicable to killing animals.

Comment: I would vote to close this as too broad.

Comment: I think this can be dealt with piecemeal: US, EU, and ignore anything in Europe that is not in the EU. The US part is reasonably manageable, I think.

Answer (score 1):

[7 USC 1902](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/7/1902) allows one of two slaughter methods:

> (a) in the case of cattle, calves, horses, mules, sheep, swine, and
>   other livestock, all animals are rendered insensible to pain by a
>   single blow or gunshot or an electrical, chemical or other means that
>   is rapid and effective, before being shackled, hoisted, thrown, cast,
>   or cut; or
>
> (b) by slaughtering in accordance with the ritual requirements of the
>   Jewish faith or any other religious faith that prescribes a method of
>   slaughter whereby the animal suffers loss of consciousness by anemia
>   of the brain caused by the simultaneous and instantaneous severance of
>   the carotid arteries with a sharp instrument and handling in
>   connection with such slaughtering.

Individual states typically have versions of this law (so that it's not necessary to make a federal case out of a violation), for example in Washington we have [RCW 61.50](http://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=16.50&full=true) which requires using a humane method, defined as:

> (a) A method whereby the animal is rendered insensible to pain by
>   mechanical, electrical, chemical, or other means that is rapid and
>   effective, before being shackled, hoisted, thrown, cast, or cut; or
>
> (b) a method in accordance with the ritual requirements of any
>   religious faith whereby the animal suffers loss of consciousness by
>   anemia of the brain caused by the simultaneous and instantaneous
>   severance of the carotid arteries with a sharp instrument.